# Why does my code generate the Cumulative distribution function (CDF) greater than 1?

Tags: matlab, probability, probability-density

I want to plot Cumulative distribution function (CDF) of a set of values, Z using MATLAB. When I use the following code, the CDF would not be between 0 and 1! I would appreciate if you could help me.

```
function plot_cdf(Z)    
numberbin=100;
[n,x] =hist(Z,numberbin);
pdf=n/sum(n(:))/diff(x(1:2));
cdf = cumsum(pdf);
plot(cdf)    
end
```

Comment: It would help people trying to help you if you provided sample `Z` values.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
cdf = cumsum(pdf) * diff(x([1 2]));
```

This is because the cdf is the integral of the pdf. To compute the integral, you approximate it as a [Riemann sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum): sum the function values (`cumsum(pdf)`) and multiply by their separation along the *x* axis (`diff(x([1 2]))`).